# Symfony ManyToOne return same value for select

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

In symfony 4, I've `Customer` and `Title` table:

```
Customer table:
id INT
name VARCHAR(32)
title_id TINYINT [FK]

Title table:
id INT
code VARCHAR(8)
name VARCHAR(24)
```

Supplier entity has been created:

```
/**
 * Supplier
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="supplier", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="title_id", columns={"title_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Supplier
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="int", nullable=false, options={"unsigned"=true})
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=48, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var \Title
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Title")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="title_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $title;


    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTitle(): ?Title
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setTitle(?Title $title): self
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

And Title entity too:

```
/**
 * Title
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="title")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Title
{
    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="code", type="string", length=8, nullable=false)
     */
    private $code;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=24, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    public function getId(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getCode(): ?string
    {
        return $this->code;
    }

    public function setCode(string $code): self
    {
        $this->code = $code;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

And this is my SupplierType:

```
class SupplierType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('title')
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Supplier::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

My create form is default generated with `console make:crud` -> Supplier

The problem is: my combobox at create supplier has identical title value:

```
<select id="supplier_title" name="supplier[title]" class="form-control">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1" selected="selected">TOKO</option>
    <option value="1" selected="selected">TOKO</option>
    <option value="1" selected="selected">TOKO</option>
</select>
```

What went wrong?

**Note**:

- I've another table, `SupplierBank` that has `ManyToOne` relation to `Supplier`. The combobox data is normal.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the puzzle! I leave the answer here for everyone stuck in similar problem.

For my case, **I generate the entity from existing database**. Some of my table use data type **tinyint**. One of the thumb rule of using symfony: **DO NOT USE TINYINT for PRIMARY KEY**! It will translated to boolean. So, when I generate the entity from table with tinyint, it translated to boolean. When I rename all boolean to smallint and/or int, it solved!

A pity symfony doesn't have tinyint data type. Though, they have their own consideration.